# How to prevent brew from installing a copy of Python?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, package-managers

Python 3.7 is manually installed on my system, located in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

However, Homebrew still considers Python as a *missing* dependency for a formula which needs it (i.e., when typing `brew missing`).

How can I tell Homebrew that Python is already installed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `brew` will let you replace its own Python with another one. If a recipe specifies python as a dependency, that means `brew`'s Python.

If you are concerned about `brew`'s Python responding to the `python` command instead of your existing 3.7 installation this is best managed by adjusting your `$PATH` environment variable so that the directory containing the framework Python comes before `/usr/local` or wherever `brew` installs things on your machine. This *might* modify the Python that brew-installed software sees.